# get data from saved query into a text box on a report

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that has 18 text boxes and a query that returns those 18 field based on a date.  The query was created in the QBE Grid ans saved. In the recordsource for the report I have the name of the query (BatCageQry1). Each textbox is bound to a value in the query (Supervisor text box is bount to LSupervisor which is a field in the query. How do I get the data from the query into the text boxes? I have read that text boxes don't have record sources and looked at some examples that made no sense. I don't want to use combo boxes in the report. Using window 10 and office 365 32 bit.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new report using the wizard, and having it get the data from saved query, and all the text boxes worked.  But I had to rearrange all boxes and copy the labels from the original report. Thus I was able to get data from a query into text boxes. Jpl